# Chrome add breakpoint on future function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, debugging

I use debugger A LOT and chrome is wonderful for debugging JS.
I usually play with `debugger;` statements or clicked breakpoints when I know the function name.

I have production issues and I can't deploy `debugger;` or logging statements.

I wan't to add a breakpoint in a function that is reloaded with AJAX request. There fore, when I type the function name in the console, the shown code is not the one executed once reloaded.

Is there a way to add a function call wrapper in which I insert a debugger; that allows me to step info my fresh reloaded function.

Lets try an example :

Here is a page : index.php

```
<script>
$.post("ajax/function", function () {
    $("#result").html(data);
});
</script>
<div id=result></div>
```

Here is the ajax/function response

```
<script>
function iWantToDebugYou() {
   // .... I want to debug this function
   var thereisabugInThisCode = true;
   if (thereisabugInThisCode) {
       $("#theResultDiv").html("BAD THING HAPPENED");
   }
}
iWantToDebugYou();
</script>
<div id=theResultDiv>Hello world</div>
```

Comment: If I understand, you're overridding a function via an AJAX call somehow? Why wouldn't you paste the new function directly into the console? And where is your minimal, complete, verifiable example?

Comment: The AJAX response indeed override the function if called twice. But this is actually not a minimal example. I cannot paste the function as once executed, I cannot run it another time. And it is ran when the AJAX functions returns. I will try to enrich the question with an example